# WSO2 DAS with Couchbase

Tags: wso2, couchbase

I have tried to connect WSO2 with external sources like Oracle but I'm not able to do it with NoSQL Couchbase.
could you, please, guide me on how I can integrate WSO2 DAS with Couchbase ?
can we do it through Custom datasource?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK DAS doesn't support couch db. https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Implementation+With+Different+Database+Types

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne the question is about Couchbase, not CouchDB

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with WSO2, but if you can connect it to ODBC/JDBC, then there are drivers for [Couchbase](https://developer.couchbase.com/) available from [Simba - ODBC and JDBC for Couchbase](http://www.simba.com/drivers/couchbase-odbc-jdbc/) (Note that ODBC/JDBC may not be as performant as direct Couchbase operations because of the translation that's going on)